# Prove that if $p$ is prime, $(a,p)=1$ and $(n,p-1)=1$, then $x^n=a \mod p$ has exactly one solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Prove that if $p$ is prime, $(a,p)=1$ and $(n,p-1)=1$, then $x^n=a \mod p$ has exactly one solution.

This is such a hard one. I'll display my own current attempt.

$x^n=a \mod p$ has exactly one solution. 
iff
$x^n-a= \mod p$ has exactly one solution.

I am stuck.

I don't have any knowledge of ring theory, only elementary number theory, up to chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: I think there may be a connection to primitive roots, since they specify that (n,p-1) = 1. Maybe try and look at the problem from that perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $p$ is prime, the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. You can then prove that the map $x\to x^n$ is a group automorphism using the fact that $(n,p-1)=1$.